# C++ 11 thread class member function in for loop gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, segmentation-fault

I have 8 datasets stored as pairs in a vector and decide to pass one by one into a class and do some job with a function inside that class. Segmentation fault is generated. Here is my code:

```
vector<thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // generate 8 threads
    LogOdd CEB; // create LogOdd obj
    CEB.set_data(coord[i].second, coord[i].first); // pass parameters to private members
    threads.push_back(thread(&LogOdd::scan, &CEB));
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){    
    threads[i].join();
}
```

the class looks like:

```
class LogOdd {
private:
    string sequence;
    string chromosome;
public:
    void scan() { // function to be threaded
    ...
    }
    void set_data(string SEQUENCE, string CHROMOSOME) { // set parameters
        sequence = SEQUENCE;
        chromosome = CHROMOSOME;
    }
};
```

I'm pretty sure the segmentation fault generated in the first threading for loop but have no idea... I know this topic might be a duplicate but I have done a lot of search already. Please help!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for answering my question. I edited my code in 2 ways and they work!

```
vector<thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // generate 8 threads
    LogOdd * CEB = new LogOdd; // create LogOdd obj
    CEB->sequence = coord[i].second;
    CEB->chromosome = coord[i].first;
    threads.push_back(thread(&LogOdd::scan, CEB));
}
```

Another way I do is storing all 8 obj into a vector first and then assign to threads:

```
vector<thread> threads;
vector<LogOdd> LogOddvec;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    LogOdd CEB;
    CEB.sequence = coord[i].second;
    CEB.chromosome = coord[i].first;
    LogOddvec.push_back(CEB);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    threads.push_back(thread(&LogOdd::scandinuc, &LogOddvec[i]));
}
```

Comment: Think about what the lifetime of this object is: `LogOdd CEB;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at these lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // generate 8 threads
    LogOdd CEB; // create LogOdd obj
    ...
    threads.push_back(thread(&LogOdd::scan, &CEB));
    ...
}
```

Inside the loop you define the variable `CEB`. You pass a pointer to this variable to the thread. Then the loop iterates, and `CEB` *goes out of scope and is destructed*.

That means the threads are passed a pointer to a destructed object. Dereferencing that pointer in the threads will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which is a very common caues of crashes like yours.

The simplest solution is to allocate the `LogOdd` object dynamically with `new`. A possibly better solution would be to pass `CEB` by value to the thread functions. Another solution would be to pass `coord[i].second` and `coord[i].first` as arguments to the thread function (or possibly a constant reference to `coord[i]`), and have the thread function create its own `LogOdd` object.

Comment: Or combine your solutions and pass a smart pointer by value - then it doesn't need a copy operator

Comment: If LogOdd is movable and moving is cheap, you can actually omit any dynamic memory allocation and call thread([ceb = std::move(CEB)] mutable { ceb.scan(); })

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! @Some programmer dude although you have stated the 3rd solution clearly, I'd like to ask how to "have the thread function create its own LogOdd object"...

Comment: @Fei-manHsu Just pass `coord[i]` as argument to the thread function (is it a `std::pair`?). And in the thread function define `LogOdd CEB;` followed by e.g. `CEB.set_data(coord.second, coord.first);`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in `LogOdd CEB`. You allocate it statically inside a block, so it gets destroyed by the end of the block, which is at the end of iteration in which it has been created.

You are then using a pointer to object that no longer exists, which ends up being undefined behaviour. Easiest solution would be to use `new` to allocate it dynamically.